# nc server does not work if launched on startup

Tags: bash, shell-script, embedded, webserver, busybox

I wrote a (ba)sh script to write to a file the content received from a POST method:

```
#!/bin/sh
PORT=$1
FILE=$2

while true
do
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n" | ./busybox-armv7l nc -l -p $PORT | tr '[\r\n]' '#' | sed "s/.*##//" | tr '#' '\n' | ( read line; echo $line > $FILE; echo $line )
done
```

If I launch the script from the console it works fine:

```
./server 5000 /tmp/foo
```

and the specified file is filled with the data received.
But when I try to launch it on startup it doesn't work anymore. Because it's a commercial embedded device I have a script in `/use/sbin/init.sh` where I can add my own scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin/:/usr/sbin:/sbin

mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
mount -t tmpfs none /tmp

export MACHINE_ID=`cat /sys/devices/soc0/machine | sed 's/ /-/g'`

echo 8 >/proc/sys/kernel/printk

mkdir -p /dev/pts
mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts -ogid=5,mode=620

ln -snf /tmp /dev/shm

mkdir /tmp/sd
mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0p1 /tmp/sd -o rw

depmod -a

/etc/init.d/syslog start

ifconfig lo up
ifconfig eth0 up
sleep 1s
mii-tool --reset

ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.132

[ ! -x /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key ] || /usr/sbin/dropbearkey -t rsa -f /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key
[ ! -x /etc/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key ] || /usr/sbin/dropbearkey -t dss -f /etc/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key

/usr/sbin/dropbear -r /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key -p 22

/home/root/server.sh 5000 /tmp/foo > /tmp/log.txt &

/bin/sh
```

it happens that the `nc` server doesn't receive anything and the `log.txt` is continuously filled with `\n`.

Do you see something obviously wrong here?
In which way I can further debug the issue?

Comment: Maybe nc in listening mode is not the best choice for that.

Comment: I'm aware of that but I have no other choice. The device is *very* limited. Indeed, it works fine - it doesn't work only if I launch it on startup as described.

Comment: xinetd or redir might be better solution for what you want. `nc` in listening mode is a one shot solution, and putting it on a loop might create instability. You might even already have xinetd installed. I prefer redir, small as well.

Comment: As said I've no alternatives: neither `xinetd` nor `redir`. And `nc` could be used in a loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640054/minimal-web-server-using-netcat.

Comment: I did not say it is not possible. I do not advise it as a good quality solution. For instance, it might not account for sockets in TIME_WAIT state.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote to close; question should be closed because nobody's going to be able to answer it because the device environment is weird and the device is not identified. I want to answer "send standard error to /dev/null" but there's no way to verify if it's right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths instead of relative ones, so the requested executable could be find even when the current directory is different:

```
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n" | /home/root/busybox-armv7l nc -l -p $PORT | tr '[\r\n]' '#' | sed "s/.*##//" | tr '#' '\n' | ( read line; echo $line > $FILE; echo $line )
```